# StandardWrapperValve[web.dbServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet web.dbServlet threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish, hsqldb

I try to insert some information in the table, but get such an error (NullPointerException). Maybe it causes of empty request, but I'm not sure.

Here is a log with error: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbVoe.jpg)

First Servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/clientServlet")
public class clientServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    Client client = new Client();
    client.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
    client.setSurname(request.getParameter("surname"));
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute(sessionKey.client, client);
    response.sendRedirect("addTour.html");

}
```

The second one:

```
@WebServlet("/tourServlet")
public class tourServlet extends HttpServlet{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    Tour tour = new Tour();
    tour.setCountryTo(request.getParameter("countryTo"));
    tour.setAmountOfDays(request.getParameter("amountOfDays"));
    session.setAttribute(sessionKey.tour, tour);
    response.sendRedirect("final.jsp");
}
```

Problem appears in this Servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/dbServlet")
public class dbServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public dbServlet() {
    super();
}

 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse   response) throws ServletException, IOException { 
    try {
        IRepositoryCatalog catalog = new  RepositoryCatalog("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/workdb");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Client client = (Client) session.getAttribute(sessionKey.client);
        Tour tour = (Tour) session.getAttribute(sessionKey.tour);
        catalog.Clients().add(client);
        catalog.saveAndClose();

        catalog.Tours().add(tour);
        catalog.saveAndClose();
        catalog.saveAndClose();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException a) {
        a.printStackTrace();    
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first impression i can say that maybe the first and second servlet are for a POST method so doing a doGet and trying to 'getParameter' you will get empty object and so throw a NullPointerException. Can you post something about your view?

(I would comment but i can't yet)